# Calling controller method from JQuery calls occurs twice and also returning error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Hi guys i have posted a similar post before, but that is for another, now i face a strange and odd issue with my Jquery code. Here i was calling a controller method using Jquery but it is calling twice , so that may cause two entries in my db. Here is what i have written in my JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var instructorUrl = '@Url.Action("ApplyToBecomeInstructor", "InstructorApplication")';
        var currentUser = '@Model.CurrentUserId';
        var user = [];
        var educationList = [];
        var experience = $('#Experience').val();
        var isWilling = $('#WillingToTravel').is(":checked");
        $('#editorRows .editorRow').each(function () {
            var education = {
                UniversityOrCollege: $(this).find('.university').val(),
                AreaOfStudy: $(this).find('.area').val(),
                Degree: $(this).find('.degree').val(),
                YearReceived: $(this).find('.year').val()
            }
            educationList.push(education);
        });
        var applicationFromView = {
            EducationalBackgrounds: educationList,
            CurrentUserId: currentUser,
            Experience: experience,
            WillingToTravel: isWilling
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: instructorUrl,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(applicationFromView),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                return false;
            },
            error: function (data) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my controller action looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ApplyToBecomeInstructor(InstructorApplicationViewModel applicationFromView)
{
    Student thisStudent = this.db.Students.Where(o => o.StudentID == applicationFromView.CurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault();
    List<PaulSchool.Models.EducationalBackground> educationList = new List<EducationalBackground>();
    foreach (var educate in applicationFromView.EducationalBackgrounds)
    {
        var education = new Models.EducationalBackground
        {
            YearReceived = educate.YearReceived,
            Degree = educate.Degree,
            AreaOfStudy = educate.AreaOfStudy,
            UniversityOrCollege = educate.UniversityOrCollege
        };
        educationList.Add(education);
    }
    var instructorApplication = new InstructorApplication
    {
        BasicInfoGatheredFromProfile = thisStudent,
        Experience = applicationFromView.Experience,
        EducationalBackground = new List<Models.EducationalBackground>(),
        WillingToTravel = applicationFromView.WillingToTravel
    };
    instructorApplication.EducationalBackground.AddRange(educationList);
    this.db.InstructorApplication.Add(instructorApplication);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
    return this.Redirect("Index");
}
```

Error message showing is JSON Parsing error.. but it is confusing to me.
I really wondered why this is happening, can anybody please take a look and help me?

Comment: You need to return false from outside the `ajax` callbacks. see my answer and example

Comment: Are you using a <form/> tag with an action? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code does:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () { // attach a click handler for the button.
...
...
// Look for elements inside the button... 
UniversityOrCollege: $(this).find('.university').val(),
```

Change from `click` to `submit`:

```
$('#formId').submit(function (e) { 
    ...
    // Now "this" is the form - not the button.
    // Look for elements inside the <form>
    UniversityOrCollege: $(this).find('.university').val(), 
    // Prevent the default form submition
    return false // Or: e.preventDefault();
```

Another tip: use jQuery [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

Comment: This might be a better way to handle a submit than checking for clicking on the button, but this assumes he has a form. How would this prevent the form from being submitted twice?

Comment: @Cixate. Yes he just need to disable the button and `e.preventDefualt()`

Comment: Right, just saying you might need to point that out as his original code makes no attempt to prevent multiple clicks/submits and is likely the root of his issue.

Comment: @Cixate. I added it now thanks. And actually he does try to preventDefault. He returns false but from inside the ajax callback...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think we're talking about two different things. Even with a submit handler, if someone clicks the submit button twice before the page reloads, two submits will get posted to the server (even if you block even propagation as it become 2 events). Yes, when using a submit handler you should prevent event propagation.

Comment: @Cixate. I'm not sure he wants to disable the submit button. he had two submits because he didn't prevent the default. he can disable the button with : `$('#btnSubmit').attr('disable', 'disable')`

Comment: @Gdoron:- Thanks buddy this really helped me, i likes the serialize function very much

Comment: @gdoron:- but the issue is resolved but my education list in server side does not contains all the items why is that so?

Comment: here in clide iam building the list using a each function in jquery , but when it reaches server side after seriaized it contains only 1 item, why is that so?

Comment: @Febin. I'm sorry I was off, for half an hour. You should check the params the Controller get. The `ModelBinder` probably can't match the data. (Of course you should verify that the list in't empty on in the client side. )

Comment: great comment dude, actually that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

`$('#btnSubmit').click()` will fire every time the button is pressed. Often users double click buttons even though it only needs a single click or if you don't give any indication that something is happening they get impatient and click it again. You need some way to determine if the request has been made. There's ways to do this client and server side. The easiest client side way is to disable the button to prevent multiple clicks:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    // Disable the button so it can't be clicked twice accidentally
    $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    //...
    $.ajax({
        //...
        complete: function() {
            // Make sure we re-enable the button on success or failure so it can be used again
            $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```